# Task Parallel library implementation on mono?

Tags: c#, mono, task-parallel-library

Does Mono implement Task Parallel library? If so, how does performance compare between .NET and mono.

Comment: partial answer: yes mono does implement the task parallel library: http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6#ParallelFx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was implemented in Mono release 2.6.

[From the release notes:](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6)

> ParallelFx
>
> This release includes some components of the ParallelFx framework that were developed as part of Google Summer Of Code 2008 & 2009. More precisely, it contains the Task Parallel Library and Data Structures For Coordination.
>
> Using ParallelFx, you can easily develop software that can automatically take advantage of the parallel potential of today multicore machines. For that purpose, several new constructs like futures, parallel loops or concurrent collections are now available.
>
> To use this code you have to manually enable the .NET 4 profile using the --with-profile4=yes switch at configure stage.

Answer (score 5):

In my own experience, I have a highly parallel program in C# for the learning and classification of gene sequence data which makes very heavy usage of the Task Parallel Library features such as Parallel.ForEach, Parallel.For, Task.Factory.StartNew(), and many structures from from the Collections.Concurrent namespace (Blocking Collections, Concurrent Dictionaries, Concurrent Bags etc).  In short, my application's performance on Linux using mono is many many times slower.  I am still trying to figure this out.  I can run it from the mono console in windows with similar performance.

I have experimented with using mono's sgen garbage collector to no avail.  The performance of my application on a Linux server running with mono is still dramatically slower.

**Learning 8,258 sequences:**
0:17 vs. 1:59 m:ss on Linux

**Classify 921 sequences:**
2.29 seconds vs. 11:05 mm:ss on Linux

See screen shots below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Jake, what version of Mono are you using?  Did you ever see an improvement with this performance?

Comment: I was using Mono 3.2.3.  I was never able to get this resolved and abandoned Mono altogether for this project.  I built a Windows box with dual liquid cooled hexacore processors and 128GB of RAM.  However, I would have a ton of university resources at my disposal, if I could get this performing well on Linux...  It is possible that the Mono version on Linux was slightly older, but it had to have at least supported .NET 4.5.  Otherwise, my program would not have executed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the min/maxthreads?

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(mWorker, mWorker);
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 10);
```

You are operating way beyond me, but I found that nothing was getting done.  So I set it to 5 * number of cpu cores and it snapped right out of it!