# Parallel.For is not working on monodevelop 2.8.6.3+dfsg-2

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I am very new to monodevelop. and trying to investigate .Net Parallelism on MONO. as of i read in the previous posts Parallelism(TPL) is not completely implemented on MONO.

Can any one please let me know more about my problem and if Parallelism(TPL) is allowed to do it on MONO then please let me know hoe to use it.

Hope to here from some one soon.

Thanks and Regards,
Veeresh

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170846/task-parallel-library-implementation-on-mono

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the problem you have, can you explain it?

MonoDevelop is just an IDE, it is not the one which has the implementation of Parallel, but Mono. So what version of Mono do you have installed? TPL framework has been included since 2.6, and according to [the release notes of version 2.10](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#Parallel_Framework_Updates#Major_Highlights) there has been some improvements in that release.

So if you're not using 2.10.x, upgrade, and if the problem still persists, upgrade to unstable version 2.11.3 or higher before to test before filing a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my question is, I am trying to implement "Parallel.For" on MONO and its giving an error like "The 'Mainwindow' does not contain the definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' of type 'Mainwindow' could be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)" Following is the code I am usin-----------------------Parallel.For(2, 20, (i) =>
{
var result = SumRootN(i);
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
textBlock1.Text += "root " + i.ToString() + " " + result.ToString() + Environment.NewLine), null);
});

Comment: If i take out "this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>" statement code is working fine.my doubt is, as of i read on the Internet dispatcher will dispatch the task that is done by the worker thread to UI thread for display. Please have a look at the link, same thing i am trying to implement on MONO "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx"

Comment: You still haven't said what version of Mono are you using.